# ClassDefNotFoundException using FacebookSDK

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am developing an app using FacebookSDK, now I'm integrating Facebook login to the my app. My problem is a NoClassDefFoundError at the initialization of my integration activity.

There is the logcat output:

> 05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671): Process: com.tuntzme, PID: 23671
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tuntzme.controller.fragments.IntegracaoFragment$1
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at com.tuntzme.controller.fragments.IntegracaoFragment.(IntegracaoFragment.java:24)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at com.tuntzme.controller.activities.ActivityIntegracao.onCreate(ActivityIntegracao.java:21)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   05-08 17:05:16.214: E/AndroidRuntime(23671):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is my activity:

```
public class ActivityIntegracao extends ActionBarActivity {

private IntegracaoFragment integracaoFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_integracao);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        integracaoFragment = new IntegracaoFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, integracaoFragment).commit();
    } else {
        integracaoFragment = (IntegracaoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    }
}

public static class IntegracaoFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "IntegracaoFragment";

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_integracao, container, false);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        TuntzMeApplication.instance().setFacebookLoginButton(authButton);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // Abrir activity map
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sincronizacao, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the FBAndroid apk?

Comment: Yes I did install the app via play store :/

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, the problem was with my build patch, seems like I accidentally manually added the FacebookSDK to the Java BuildPath, that was causing the issue. Thank you anyway